# Interpretations and models in propositional logic

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus

I am trying to understand model vs. interpretation of sentences vs. theories, with respect to a propositional calculus.

Is a model of a wff just a sentence that is true under some interpretation?

Or a set of wffs that are all true under some interpretation?

Or when an interpretation satisfies a wff (or set of wffs)?

Does it make sense to say that an interpretation is a model if all valid propositions are true? Or an interpretation being a model iff all theorems from the theory are still valid under the interpretation?

Comment: What books are you reading?  There's a certain variety in definitions.

Comment: It's possible that considering propositional logic is making this *too* simplified, and that, at the cost of some additional complexity, the distinctions would be clearer in predicate logic. For example, you could identify a truth function $\mathsf{Prop}\to\mathbf{2}$ with a subset of $\mathsf{Prop}$, the set of propositions. Doing this for first-order logic, though, doesn't make as much sense. (The equivalent would be making a family of relations, i.e. subsets of a cartesian product, indexed by arity, $n$, of the form $\mathsf{Pred}_n\times D^n$. The propositional case is then $n=0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Interpretation of a truth-functional propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Interpretation_of_a_truth-functional_propositional_calculus) :

> An *interpretation* of a truth-functional [i.e. *classic*] propositional calculus $\text P$ is an assignment to each propositional symbol $\text P$ of one or the other (but not both) of the truth values truth ($\text T$) and falsity ($\text F$), and an assignment to the connective symbols of $\text P$ of their usual truth-functional meanings.

*Example* : Let the language of $\text P$ made of the following list of prop symbols : $\text {At} = \{p_0, p_1,\ldots \}$ and let $\{ \lor, \lnot \}$ the set of *connectives*.

An *interpretation* is an assignment $v : \text {At} \to \{ \text T, \text F \}$ such that, e.g. $v(p_0)= \text T$ and $v(p_1)= \text F$, etc.

Using $v$ and the truth tables for $\lor$ and $\lnot$ we can easily compute the truth value of a formula whatever of $\text P$, like e.g. $(p_0 \lor \lnot p_1)$.

If $\varphi$ is a formula of $\text P$ and we have $v(\varphi)= \text T$, we say that the interpretation $v$ *satisfies* formula $\varphi$ (and we can write : $v \vDash \varphi$).

> A formula of propositional logic is true under an interpretation iff the interpretation assigns the truth value $\text T$ to that formula. If a formula is true under an interpretation, then that interpretation is called a *model* of that formula.

Thus, an interpetation *satisfies* a formula $\varphi$ iff it is a *model* of the formula.

---

In (classic) propositional logic a formula $\varphi$ is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) (or *valid*) iff it is true in every interpretation, i.e. such that :

> $v \vDash \varphi$, for every *assignment* $v$.

Examples of tautologies : $(p_0 \to p_0), (p_0 \lor \lnot p_0)$.

Comment: So an interpretation can be a model of a formula, $v \models \varphi$, but then we are also able to say a set of wffs "models" a formula, e.g. $\Gamma \models \varphi$? Or is this wrong and it's more accurate to say $\Gamma \models \varphi$ means $\varphi$ is satisfied in all models of $\Gamma$?

Comment: @user525966 - Yes; the symbol $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, with $\Gamma$ a **set** of formulas, means that $\varphi$ is a [semantic consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) of $\Gamma$. See your previous post [How is my understanding of ⊢,⊨,→, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910093/how-is-my-understanding-of-vdash-vdash-to-etc)

Comment: I understand it is a semantic consequence -- what I mean is if my use of "models" here is correct

Comment: @user525966 The second one. You may be confused by the command \models. This symbol is used in two totally different ways. $\mathcal M\models \Gamma $ “the structure $\mathcal M$ is a model for the set of sentences $\Gamma$” is the use where “models” is a apt verb. The usage $\Gamma\models \phi$ would never be put into English as “$\Gamma$ is a model for $\phi.$.” (In fact, some model theory books, that don’t need to worry about confusion with the syntactical notion, use $\vdash$ here instead.)

Comment: @user525966 the second usage would be put into English as “$\phi$ is a semantic consequence of $\Gamma.$”

Comment: @user525966 no. A model of what? All valid propositions are true in any interpretation whatsoever. That’s what it means to be valid.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense