# Models in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I want to get an understanding of what precisely a model means in a **predicate logic**, in terms of environments, lookup tables, predicate and function sets, universe, etc. 
Also, **what are we supposed to write in an answer, when we are asked to find a model that satisfies a formula.**(The second part of my question makes it different from this one: [Confusion over the definition of "model"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959629/confusion-over-the-definition-of-model) and also I wanted to confirm the meaning of model in predicate logic and if it's different from the one in propositional logic)

My interpretation of model is that they consist of a set of values for a given environment/lookup table that consists of matching to the values corresponding to the values that predicates and functions would give to the elements of the Universe of the model that are valid for the functions/predicates themselves or what we say are the interpretations of the functions/models in the model.

Please excuse if my question is not very appropriate or my interpretation is way too wrong.