# Is my intuition for ${\vdash}$ and ${\models}$ correct?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

I just want to check my idea for what exactly is meant by ${\vdash}$ and ${\vDash}$ is correct (I am a noob to logic).

${S\vdash t}$ means "$t$ is provably true using finitely many elements of $S$ within that system", whereas ${S\vDash t}$ means "$t$ is true given $S$", but doesn't make any statements about whether we could prove it within that system $S$. Is this essentially correct? Thank you.

Comment: See [wiki/Logical Consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models). What do you mean by *system*? The symbols read “from $Γ$ we derive $φ$”, meaning $φ$ is provable given $Γ$, and “from $Γ$ we conclude $φ$”, meaning $φ$ is true given $Γ$, for $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ respectively, where $Γ$ is a set of formulae and $φ$ is a single formula. The formal system within which we derive or conclude is denoted as a subscript to either $\vdash$ or $\vDash$ and does not appear to the left of these symbols.

Comment: [Multiple copies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910093/how-is-my-understanding-of-vdash-vdash-to-etc) of the same question available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you have it quite right.

---

"$S\models\varphi$" is defined purely **semantically**: it means "If $\mathcal{M}$ is a structure satisfying each sentence in $S$, then $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\varphi$ as well." In particular, this notion is *secondary* to the notion of a sentence being true in a structure (which uses the same
"$\models$" symbol, incidentally).

Meanwhile, "$S\vdash\varphi$" is **not** actually fully precise! It really only makes sense once we specify a *proof system* $\mathfrak{P}$. This is a totally different object from $S$ and $\varphi$; basically, it's just a set of rules for deriving sentences from sets of sentences. If we can derive $\varphi$ from $S$ via $\mathfrak{P}$, we write "$S\vdash_\mathfrak{P}\varphi$."

A priori these are two totally different things, and we can whip up silly "proof systems" which are obviously unrelated to the semantics: e.g. "bogus ponens," the proof system which lets you deduce anything from anything.

(Note that I haven't defined "proof system" precisely - nor am I going to. There are various definitions floating around in the literature, with no one particular one being universally accepted. And there are further subtleties which can emerge, see e.g. [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnl/1235423708).)

---

So how are these connected, and why do we abuse notation by writing "$\vdash$" instead of "$\vdash_\mathfrak{P}$?"

Well, it turns out that for a wide variety of $\mathfrak{P}$s we in fact have **soundness and completeness** of the proof system with respect to the semantics, that is, $$S\vdash_\mathfrak{P}\varphi\quad\iff\quad S\models\varphi$$ (the left-to-right direction is soundness, the right-to-left is completeness - and it's the latter which is by far the more interesting direction). Moreover, since we're specifically interested in the semantics above, proof systems which are *not* sound and complete aren't generally of interest.

This means that **we can usually write "$\vdash$" without fear of serious confusion**, since all the "reasonable" proof systems we look at will behave identically here. But in other contexts, and for certain questions (like questions about proof *length*), the specific proof system may matter a lot. So when first learning this stuff it's a good idea to fix a single proof system from the get-go, and only generalize later once the basics are understood.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I think I see - you are saying that ${S \vDash t}$ means essentially "for any proof system such that $S$ is all true, then $t$ is true"; whereas ${S \vdash_{\mathfrak{P}} t}$ means "using the proof system ${\mathfrak{P}}$, and given all of that in ${S}$, there is a proof"?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose No, $\models$ has *nothing* to do with proof systems at all (in terms of its *definition*, at least; per the completeness theorem they are in fact related, but that happens later) - it's just about [(first-order) structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Structures_and_first-order_logic). You can study $\models$ without ever thinking about proof systems at all (not that you *should*) - for example, while some texts prove compactness for $\models$ as a corollary of the completeness theorem, you can just prove compactness "purely semantically."

Comment: Ok, I see. So I should think of ${S\vDash t}$ more like "if some structure satisfies everything in ${S}$, it also satisfies $t$" - that "structure" hasn't got anything necessarily to do with any particular proof system; whereas ${S \vdash_{\mathfrak{P}} t}$ says "Given the proof system ${\mathfrak{P}}$, and given everything in $S$ is satisfied by this proof system - I can prove ${t}$ also"?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yes, that's exactly right. FWIW I'd recommend studying $\models$ on its own first, and only turning to $\vdash$ once you have a solid understanding of first-order structures. But ultimately your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!